# cron jobs dow and mon exception

Tags: cron

Today 2017-25-09 and monday and I have seen a entry cron job in syslog. My crontab:

```
# m  h  dom mon dow   user    command
  30 05 18  9   1     root    /bin/bash [--job route--]
```

If today is 25th, why cron start job with `dom` to 18 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you have both dow and dom set. Cron 'or's those together.  Your cron job is starting on the 18th OR the 1st day of the week.  So since today is the first day of the week its starting.  If you dont want that to happen dont set DOW.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: thanks! I tried before asking, to find something like this but i failed. From you link: "While normally the job is executed when the time/date specification fields all match the current time and date, there is one exception: if both "day of month" (field 3) and "day of week" (field 5) are restricted (not "*"), then one or both must match the current day."